# Port Reading (Scale Weight) error somewhere

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hi Code shown bellow...

trying to read from com port and displaying a weight sent
from a scale indicator into a textbox, i get an error saying -

WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.textBox1_TextChanged(object, System.EventArgs)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

im new to c# please help

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
namespace Read_serial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Open();

            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string line = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), line);
        }

        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);
        private void LineReceived(string line)
        {
            //What to do with the received line here
            textBox1.Text = line;

            progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(line);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this in visual studio, but note your first line:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Compare to:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The ; at the end pretty much says "I'm done!" ... therefore there is no body.

I'm not sure how the '}' gets right after that line; is there code from above missing? Also it is followed by statements that are typically at the top of a source file.

I would try removing that line and the bracket. Also check the other file with the form for something like textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged, remove that too - maybe you can remove the event in the IDE (been a while since I used C#). Search your solution for textbox1_textchanged to be sure.

Then re-add the event if you need it. Right now it's just screwing things up for you.